# jquery classes and subclassing

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm currently working on an existing project trying to figure out what is what.

I have this piece of code that I'm wondering what it actually does and how to call a specific function in this class:

```
(function fileactions($) {
    $(function init() {
        $(document).bind('file-delete', fileDelete);
    }
    function fileDelete() { 
        alert('do something'); 
    }
    function callThisFunction() {}
})(jQuery);
```

So I've been working like above as that code was already there, but now I need to call the function `callThisFunction()` from outside the `fileactions` object (is it even an object?).

I'm far from a javascript expert, as far as I could tell from google that this is a way of subclassing?, does this mean I'm extending jQuery with the function created in `fileactions`?

The `fileDelete` method is simple, I can just trigger an event and it'll work, and so far I've only needed functionality like that.

Comment: You are effectively creating a `fileactions` class with methods called `fileDelete` and `callThisFunction` etc . The `jQuery` is only being passed as the value for `$` (locally scoping a shortcut name for jQuery).

Comment: Why would you create a function with insufficient scope, then make it accessible by binding it to a new way invoking it (`fileDelete` - `file-delete`) which *is* in scope? I'm confused too.